# What's the difference between で and において?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

I get that において represents like the 場所, 時 and 分野. However when we are talking about a place, what is the difference?

Like why is the first one correct but not the second?

> ○ 教室で友達と昼ご飯を食べた
> × 教室において友達と昼ご飯を食べた

And again with these

> ○ 結果はホームページにおいて発表されます
> × 結果はホームページで発表されます

Answer (score 1):

In the following meanings of において, (roughly 1: place, 2: regarding, realm)

> １　動作・作用の行われる時・場所・場合を表す。「パリ―外相会議が開かれる」
>
> ２ 事物や人物について、それと関連する意を表す。…に関して。…について。「規模の大きさ―ひけをとらない」

it is not different from で. But で is much 'lighter'.

において tends to be used for something big, which makes the following odd.

- 教室において友達と昼ご飯を食べた

On the other hand

- 結果はホームページで発表されます

is in fact not that weird. If it is the result of some international competition,  において might be preferred, but in most cases, ホームページで should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

～において is a stiff expression that is found mainly in scientific articles, legal documents, formal reports and such. Besides, it's usually used when you need to put emphasis on the marked word.

教室において友達と昼ご飯を食べた sounds odd because this is not a type of sentence that appears in a formal document, but something like 昨日この教室において試験説明会が開催されました looks perfectly fine.

結果はホームページで発表されます and 結果はホームページにおいて発表されます are both perfectly fine, but the latter sounds stiffer.